# I have a college senior design question

Tags: design

I'm in my second to last year of mechanical engineering. So next year I'm going to be going into senior design. For those that have gone into any engineering course and have done senior design projects...

How are design projects chosen?
Do I chose one from a list of does a professor tell my group what he wants is to do?

If you can tell me anything about the beginning selection process thatd be really helpful to prepare me. Thanks

**
Edit: the responses are great and I appreciate them. I'm gonna take it one step further and also ask...

For those that went on to graduate school and received your Ph.D how did you choose your target research study?

There's a whole world of things you could have researched how did you choose?
**

Comment: Highly dependent on the school and any decisions they've made regarding relationships with outside (usually local) companies. It also depends on who's running the department. And, to be honest, which year it is (as things change.) At least, that's my experience. I don't think any of us can help without having attended where you are attending.

Comment: [This belongs in chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering)

Comment: The answer to this question is that it depends. My senior design project course contained us proposing project ideas, the professors then choosing some of our ideas, and then we got to choose the projects that were chosen by our professors. So for instance, I came up with two project proposals: Automatic irrigation system and neural signaling and robotics. My professor only chose the automatic irrigation system and then me and my friends got together and told our professor we wanted to be assigned that project.

Comment: But different universities probably senior design differently than others. For us, once we were assigned the project, we got our own sponsor by reaching out to various companies to help fund our project. The companies that fund your project might give you some target specifications so that they can have for your project once you're finished. If you don't get sponsored, then you come up with your specifications or your professor might. This is where the snowball starts growing quickly. Trust me, everything will be revealed to you. It won't be difficult to understand.

Comment: I had a few mentors that commented on this. One said: "Most professor's have a personality defect". Most Profs spend the rest of their lives working 60+ hour weeks because thats what they enjoy doing. To get tenure is like finals week for a few years. My other mentor said "Don't get your Phd if you don't like doing that kind of work". A Phd also takes 4-5 years of salary away and your spending money, for most positions that you could end up in, you'll never replace that salary over your lifetime. A masters is worth it, Phd not, unless you really like it.

Comment: Thank you @laptop2d but my question was "what did you do your topic on?"  Not "should I go into a PhD program?' Not to say that your input is not useful. Its just I've already gone through the pros and cons of what I want to do.

Comment: @Spurlock comments are not for answering questions, they are for whatever you want to post. I wasn't trying to answer the question

Comment: I was part of a student design team, so I did my senior design project around that, and designed an ultraviolet photometer. All in all, I took 5 lab classes my senior year, I almost didn't sleep, but I built an infrared photometer, an 8088 and a few real time systems.Most of them would have qualified for a senior design project.

Comment: At two instutions where I did final year projects, there was a list posted by the faculty: you got to pick one... and once picked it was gone so speed of decision making was critical otherwise you were left with the more difficult or less interesting choices...

Comment: @laptop2d that sounds really badass. I'm starting to get the picture now.

Comment: @everyone id still like to know other people's personal stories though...if you're willing to share them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends on the school. At my school, the senior design capstone consisted of two semesters - the first semester was selecting an idea of your choosing to be your design project, usually by generating a list of ideas and vetting them with the help of the professor and/or your group members (if it will be a group design project). Part of that vetting process will be determining which of those ideas is feasible, and after that, which of those ideas is feasible in the time frame you are allotted. A justification is required about the marketability or value of your project idea as well.

Once you have your idea, you begin researching the topic in order to plan the project. In my case, I did this part quickly and began working on the project in the first semester to get ahead of things.

It sounds like you are trying to be proactive here, which is the best way to go with these things. A good way to find ideas is to use the university library databases and just read PhD journal papers that have been published. This will give you a broad picture of where advanced research is, and possibly spark an idea of how to incorporate some of the research into a project. I also talked a lot with my professors about things I was interested in, which helped too.

Oh, and something I did which was useful... I took a 2-credit hour self-guided "research" course. I think it served as a couple of technical electives for my degree program. I did this before the senior design semesters and basically used that course to get ahead in my senior design. I created a similar piece of hardware/software to what I wanted to do in senior design, and advertised it as something with a slightly different purpose. The research courses are very unstructured and really only requires showing that you learned something. I did about half of my senior design project's technical work during that course, so I was well-prepared when I got to the real thing.

What you choose should be relevant to your particular degree path (if you have "emphases"  to add to your degree; I was a biomedical flavor of EE, so I did an ECG project). It should also be something that can either help society or be a marketable product; ideally both. Later, when you are judged, this is kind of important.

Typically, your ideas will be requested in the form of a proposal: some kind of multi-page report that summarizes your idea(s), feasibility, marketability, and a rough project plan that proves you have thought through the feasibility sufficiently.

This is based off my graduating in 2014, so somewhat recent. Hope that helps.